# Failing to load route with Angular inside of Phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm new to Angular and cannot figure out how to get a route working inside of phonegap. Here is my Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute'
])


.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
    controller: 'mainControl'
  })

$routeProvider.when('/test' , {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/test.html',
    controller: 'testControl'
  })

$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});

app.controller('mainControl' , function(){

})

app.controller('testControl' , function(){

})
```

I'm trying to access '/test' with this link inside of my main.html:

```
<span>Click <a href='/test'>here</a> to go to the test page<span>
```

When I click the link inside of ripple I'm getting a 404 in the console for localhost:4400/test/

Like I said I'm new to Angular so from what I can tell both routeProviders match up but I can't get the page to load when clicked through the link.

Help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a hashtag before the slash.

`<span>Click <a href='#/test'>here</a> to go to the test page<span>`

Hope this solves this problem.

Comment: I was literally just about to comment that the hashtag was the fix, but you beat me to it. Thank you!